# Remove product images from directory via script

Tags: magento-1.9

I need to remove all product images (small, thumbnail and base) from directory. What would be a better way to do this?

Comment: Are you talking about unassigning  product images from products?

Comment: Yes! I also want to delete the images from folders (media/catalog/product).  All of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use below code to remove image from product and also from image path

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->loadByAttribute('sku','acj005');
$MediaDir=Mage::getConfig()->getOptions()->getMediaDir();
$MediaCatalogDir=$MediaDir .DS . 'catalog' . DS . 'product';

$MediaGallery=Mage::getModel('catalog/product_attribute_media_api')->items($product->getId());

foreach($MediaGallery as $eachImge){
    $MediaDir=Mage::getConfig()->getOptions()->getMediaDir();
    $MediaCatalogDir=$MediaDir .DS . 'catalog' . DS . 'product';
    $DirImagePath=str_replace("/",DS,$eachImge['file']);
    $DirImagePath=$DirImagePath;
    // remove file from Dir

    $io     = new Varien_Io_File();
    $io->rm($MediaCatalogDir.$DirImagePath);

    $remove=Mage::getModel('catalog/product_attribute_media_api')->remove($product->getId(),$eachImge['file']);
}
```